# Javascript: Object have keys, but Object.keys returns empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

[image]

I have an object, as you can see in picture, when i console.log() it, in first row it says course is an array of 0 length. when i expand it, it says length is 1, when i do course.length it says 0. Object.keys(course).length also says 0.

What i do in my app is, I have a listview. each item on listview is expandable. each item is a container, and each container have courses. i got containers and courses from remote server. everything was working perfectly. now i'm trying to load data from local database. it's not working anymore...

Please see my simplified code :

```js
export default class Main extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
              rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
            })
    };
  }
  
  componentWillMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }
  
  fetchData(){
    let data = fetch..... //// fetches data
    let dsource = {};
    
    for(let i=0; i < data.containers.length; i++){
      let container = data.containers[i];
      dsource[i] = {
        containerId: containder.id,
        course: [],
      }
      for(let x=0; x < container.courses.length; x++){
         let course = container.courses[x];
        dsource[i].course.push({
          courseId: course.id,
          courseName: course,name
        });
      }
     }
    
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(dsource)
    });
    
  }
```

I read lots of questions on stackoverflow, many articles, but no successs :( Object.keys(Obj).length Obj.length all returns 0.
Some says because Obj.length will only show enumerable properties. i tried adding enumerable properties to object with Object.defineproperty but no changes.

any solutions? any help is highly appreciated.

The whole code (react native) :

```js
"use strict";

import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  NetInfo,
  AlertIOS,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

let SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage');
let Loading = require("./Loading");
let Accordion = require('react-native-accordion');
let DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';
import translations from './translations';
I18n.fallbacks = true;
let LOADING = {};
import CodePush from "react-native-code-push";
let { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
let db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "oc.db", location: 'default'});

export default class Courses extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
              rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
            }),
            isConnected: true,
            dataLoaded: 0,
            restartAllowed: true
        };
    }

    toggleAllowRestart() {
      this.state.restartAllowed
        ? CodePush.disallowRestart()
        : CodePush.allowRestart();

      this.setState({ restartAllowed: !this.state.restartAllowed });
    }

    sync() {
    CodePush.sync(
      {
        installMode: CodePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
        updateDialog: false
      },
    );
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
      this.setState({
        isConnected: isConnected
      });
    });

    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      'change',
      isConnected => {
        this.setState({
          isConnected: isConnected
        });
      }
    );

    this.fetchData();
    this.sync();
  }
    componentWillReceiveProps() {
      this.fetchData();
      this.setState({
        keyForCourse: Date()
      });
      if(this.props.goto == 'register'){
        Actions.register({type: 'reset'});
      }
    }

  fetchData() {
    console.log('Courses: fetchData running');
    if(this.state.isConnected == 'wifi' || this.state.isConnected == 'cell' || this.state.isConnected == 'true' || this.state.isConnected){
        this.setState({
          isLoading: true,
        });
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE active=?",['yes'], (tx, results) => {
                let len = results.rows.length;
                let row = results.rows.item(0);
                let userName = row.userName;
                let userMail = row.userMail;
                let userId = row.userId;
                ///// Getting courses list
                db.transaction((tx) => {
                      tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM containersC WHERE userId=?",[userId], (tx, results) => {
                          let dsource = {};
                          let len = results.rows.length;
                          if(len > 0){
                            for(let ind = 0; ind < len; ind++ ){
                              let cntr = results.rows.item(ind);
                              dsource[ind] = {
                                  nid: cntr.nid,
                                title: cntr.title,
                                course: [],
                                courses: {},
                              };
                              //// Get courses for each container
                              db.transaction((tx) => {
                                    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE userId=? AND container_nid=?",[userId, cntr.nid], (tx, results) => {
                                        let lenc = results.rows.length;
                                        if(lenc > 0){
                                            for(var j=0; j < lenc; j++){
                                              let crs = results.rows.item(j);
                                              console.log('Course:', crs);
                                              dsource[ind].course.push({
                                                course_id: crs.course_id,
                                                title: crs.title,
                                                cost: crs.cost,
                                                status: crs.status,
                                                period: crs.period // .time_sys
                                              });

                                              dsource[ind].courses[j] = {
                                                course_id: crs.course_id,
                                                title: crs.title,
                                                cost: crs.cost,
                                                status: crs.status,
                                                period: crs.period // .time_sys
                                              };
                                            }
                                            dsource[ind].total = lenc;
                                          }
                                        }, function(){
                                        console.log('Courses: Something went wrong Line 142');
                                      });
                                  });
                              //// End getting courses for containers
                            }
                            this.setState({
                              dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(dsource),
                              isLoading: false,
                              dataLoaded: len
                            });
                          }
                        }, (err)=>{
                          console.log('Courses: Something went wrong', err);
                        });
                    }
                );
                //// End getting courses list
              }, function(){
                console.log('Courses: Unable to select users from database');
              });
          });
      } else {
        AlertIOS.alert(
          I18n.t("no_connection_title"),
          I18n.t("no_connection_desc")
        );
      }
    }

  selectRow(d, n) {
    Actions.cdetails({cid: d, tit: n});
    //Actions.rdetails({cid: d, tit: n});
  }

  renderRow(data) {
    let header = (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', margin: 7, marginBottom: 0 }}>
          <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
            <View  style={styles.textContainer}>
              <Icon name="ios-arrow-up" color="#00a2dd" size={30}></Icon>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{data.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
    </View>
    );
    let headerOpen = (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', margin: 7, marginBottom: 0 }}>
          <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
            <View  style={styles.textContainer}>
              <Icon name="ios-arrow-down" color="#00a2dd" size={30}></Icon>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{data.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator}></View>
    </View>
    );
///////////
    let cid = [];
    let content = [];
    let cll = data.total;
    console.log('Data to render :', data);
    console.log('Courses to render :', data.course);
    for(let x=0; x < cll; x++){
      cid[x] = data.course[x].course_id;
      let courseCost;
      switch(data.course[x].cost){
        case 0:
        courseCost = I18n.t("course_fee_free");
        break;
        case 1:
        courseCost = data.course[x].cost;
        break;
      }
      content.push(
        <TouchableOpacity key={cid[x]} onPress={()=>{this.selectRow(data.course[x].course_id, data.course[x].title)}} >
        <View style={[styles.cardContainer, {marginBottom: 5}, x == 0 ? { paddingTop: 6, } : {}, x == (cll+1) ? { marginBottom: 3} : {}]} key={cid[x]} >
          <View style={styles.card}>
            <View resizeMode="cover" style={styles.cardTitleContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>{data.course[x].title}</Text>
            </View>
            <View
            style={{
                padding : 15,
              }}
              >
              <Text style={styles.cardContent}>
                <Icon name="ios-calendar" color="#00a2dd" size={10}> {data.course[x].period}</Icon>{'\n'}
                <Icon name="ios-pricetag" color="#00a2dd" size={10}> {courseCost}</Icon>
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
    let clist = (
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
      <View style={{
        padding: 6,
        paddingBottom: 0,
        borderTopColor: '#fff',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        margin: 7,
        marginTop: 0,
      }}>{content}</View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
////////////
  return (
    <Accordion
      header={header}
      headerOpen={headerOpen}
      content={clist}
      easing="easeOutCubic"
      underlayColor="#ebebeb"
    />
  );
  }

  render() {
    let content= null;
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      content = <Loading/>;
    } else {
      if(this.state.dataLoaded < 1){
      content = <View style={styles.errorContainer}>
     <View style={styles.error}>
     <Text style={styles.Errortext}>
      {I18n.t("courses_no_course_available")}
      </Text>
      </View>
     </View>;
      } else {
      content = <View style={{
        flex: 1
      }}>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
      />
      </View>;
    }
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {content}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: '#e4e7ea',
  },
  separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#d0d1d3",
  },
  scrollSpinner: {
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
  cardContainer:{
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    paddingLeft: 6,
    paddingRight: 6,
    borderColor: '#d0d1d3',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5
  },

  card:{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ffffff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    /*shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 2,
    },
    */
  },
  cardTitleContainer:{
    flex: 1,
    height: 35,
  },
  cardTitle:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 5,
    left: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 12,
    color: '#4c4b4b',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  rowContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    padding: 5,
  },
  textContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    padding: 5
  },
  title: {
    paddingTop: 7,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    color: '#00a2dd'
  },
  errorContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: '#e4e7ea',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  error: {
    marginTop: 75,
    width: width -150,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#ecebeb',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  Errortext: {
    color: '#757575'
  },
});

Courses = CodePush(Courses);
```

Comment: What is clearly your need, show us your what is wrong for you in your code ?

Comment: Did you try Object.keys(array) then get the key by the index? https://jsbin.com/huqojefiti/1/edit also some more code would help

Comment: `course` is an array of length 1 and your object is at position 0

Comment: I have updated the question with whole code. please take a loot at.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 3 factors that can cause the general behavior you describe. In your case, I think it's the first:

1. When you invoke `console.log(x)`, the Chrome console will show a summary of the object `x` at the time. However, **when you expand the object, the value is obtained again**. The detailed object you see **may have changed since the call to `console.log()`, and changes will appear in the detail**.
2. Properties may belong to an object's prototype (as opposed to "own" properties):

   ```
   > x = {a:1}
   { a: 1 }
   > y = Object.create(x)
   > y.a
   1
   > y
   {}
   > Object.keys(y)
   []
   ```
3. Properties may be non-enumerable, and won't show up in key listings. `length` is a non-enumerable property.

Comment: so its possible that my code is not running consequently, and before its fetched and puts all data to array , its trying to show content and it's length. right? i will try to use async / await to see what happens. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 const keys =[];  
    const person = {
    name : 'Jobelle',
    age :22,
    mob :8547391599
    }
    
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(tempObj).forEach(prop => {
              keys.push(prop);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Object.keys refers to *enumerable* properties. The "length" property of an array (which is also an object) is simply not enumerable.

Comment: So what do you suggest? how can i know how many items are inside array or object?

Comment: I don't think the OP is logging an array, although his wording could be understood this way. What's being logged is an object, whose property `course` shows an empty array but when expended shows a full array. *Note*:  downvote isn't from me.

Comment: First of all, explain your downvotes, so that we all can learn! Maybe I just understood something incorrectly regarding the question, but what I said IS correct in general. @Ataomega: Use `length` for determining the number of items in an *array*. Use `Object.keys` for determining the number of (enumerable) properties in an *object*. At least this is how I do it.

Comment: @frontend_dev thanks for your comment. since length was returning zero, i tried Object.keys().length , that also returned zero

Comment: @Ataomega, was it "course" or "courses" that did this? If I see this correctly from your console output, "course" is an array with one item in it. So here `Object.keys` should be zero, and `length` should be "1". But "courses" is apparently an object with one property "0". That is not the same! Here, `Object.keys().length` should indeed be "1". (Except for the case if you define this property as non-enumerable)

Comment: @frontend_dev as i was testing, i tried both. i added one course and courses , one array and other one object. tried length and Object.keys.length on both of them, none work as expected.

Comment: Sure you did the right thing? Otherwise that would be really strange. The behavior absolutely should be as I described. Maybe you have overlooked something else?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. I had what I thought was an empty object (printing the object printed `{}`). But doing `Object.keys()` on it return a length of 2.

```
// problem
const myObject = "{}"
console.log(myObject); // prints {}
console.log(Object.keys(myObject).length); // prints 2
```

The problem was that I was receiving a stringified object from the backend. Doing a JSON.parse on the returned string solved my issues.

```
// solution
const myObject = JSON.parse("{}")
console.log(myObject); // prints {}
console.log(Object.keys(myObject).length); // prints 0
```

Comment: IMO this is not at all similar to the question. You forgot to parse a JSON string, they did not know the behaviour of `console.log()`. OK you both got a .log() result that you did not expect, but for totally different and unrelated reasons.